# Will it cause any issue if I use `<<` and `+=` interchangeably for string?

Tags: ruby

I understand that a string being mutable means its value in the memory can be changed, and it being immutable means that not the value in the memory but only the reference can be changed.

Based on the result of the following code:

```
a = "foo"
b = "bar"
a.object_id # => 70218039369160
a << b # => "foobar"
a.object_id # => 70218039369160
```

can I say that a string in Ruby is mutable because the value in the same memory changed?

And the `+` method creates a new `String` object instead of changing its value:

```
a += b # => "foobar"
a.object_id # => 70218039184800
```

That's why the object id changed.

Will it cause any issue except for efficiency issue if I use `+=` instead of `<<` or vice versa? if the answer is yes, please give me an example

Comment: What do you mean by "security problem"? As I know, `<<` (shovel) is faster and cost less memory compare to `+=` because shovel operator modifies the String object rather than creating a new String object (costing memory).

Comment: You have two pretty much different questions.

Comment: It's fine to mix them. I often do things like `foo + "bar" << qux` when I want to build a string from parts but not mutate all of them and not create too many new string objects. Of course, it's usually better to just do `"#{foo}bar#{qux}"`.

Comment: @mwp The question is not about mixing them. It is about replacing one with the other.

Comment: Ah, I reread the question and I understand now. Thanks @sawa.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What kinds of security problems are you talking about? What is your threat model? Security is always relative to a threat model, it doesn't make sense to talk about security without a threat model. Also, what do you mean by using `+=` and `<<` interchangeably? They aren't interchangeable, they do different things!

Comment: @LongNguyen apologize for describe the question unclearly, my english is not perfect. the question is really about if I replace `+=` with `<<` or vice versa, except for speed difference and memory cost difference, is there any other difference? say if use `+=` all the time and never use `<<`, could I get bug?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, string is mutable, but that is only by default. It can also be made immutable. In future versions of Ruby, strings may become immutable by default.

Yes. Switching the two can cause security problems. In fact, not only that, but it can break the code and make it not work at all.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the security risk? Is there more to it than accidentally mutating the wrong variable and exposing the program to tainted data?